# Showing Zero more than one time when there is only 0 and 1 as input to fusion chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, fusioncharts

I am using fusion chart free and i am beginner to the fusion chart. I am trying to create a chart [ FCF_Bar2D ] in asp.net with C# In my datatable i am having values like this

```
col1-col2
 1- 0 
 2-0 
 3-0 
 4-0
 5-1
```

But in graph it is showing 0 two times and after that it will show 1? What is the problem?

Comment: Probably the problem is on xml data you send.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an XML similar to

```
<graph>
  <set value='0' name='1' />
  <set value='0' name='2' />
  <set value='0' name='3' />
  <set value='0' name='4' />
  <set value='1' name='5' />
</graph>
```

Please check.

Comment: Screenshot can help understand. You may try once setting numDivLines='0'